# How to access an Opportunity's Pricebook on a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, console, custom-console-components

I have a custom console component I'm using to add Product Line Items to an Opportunity.  I've been modifying a Salesforce Labs app that was built to Create Orders and add products to them.  I wand to assign the selectedPricebook to be the Pricebook from the Opportunity (line 13) rather than the first Pricebook in the list of Pricebooks (line 11).

```
    public with sharing class CreateOLI_Ext {

    private final Opportunity opp;
    public string selectedPricebook {get;set;}
    public List<PricebookEntry> pricebookEntries {get; private set;}

    public CreateOLI_Ext(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        List<Pricebook2> pricebooks = [SELECT Id, Name from Pricebook2 where IsActive = true];
        if (pricebooks.size() > 0) {
            selectedPricebook = pricebooks[0].Id;
        }
        //selectedPricebook = opp.Pricebook2Id;
        loadPricebookEntries();
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getPricebookOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<Pricebook2> pricebooks = [SELECT Id, Name from Pricebook2 where IsActive = true];
        for(Pricebook2 pricebook : pricebooks) {
          options.add(new SelectOption(pricebook.Id,pricebook.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public void loadPricebookEntries() {
        pricebookEntries = [SELECT Id, Name, Product2.Name, Product2.ProductCode,
                            UnitPrice  
                           FROM PricebookEntry
                           WHERE Pricebook2Id =: selectedPricebook and IsActive = true];
    }
}
```

Here is the Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Opportunity"
           extensions="CreateOLI_Ext" docType="html-5.0" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
    <head>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0121_Order, 'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <apex:remoteObjects >
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Product2" fields="Id,Name,ProductCode">
        </apex:remoteObjectModel>
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="OpportunityLineItem" fields="OpportunityId,UnitPrice,PricebookEntryId,Quantity">
        </apex:remoteObjectModel>
    </apex:remoteObjects>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .quantity {
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        height: 30px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .list-group-item {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: #eee;

        }
        .order-panel {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        background: #eee;
        }
        .order-item {
        padding: 0;
        border:0;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="slds">   
        <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner" style="padding: 15px;background: #E2E7ED;">

            <div class="slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-col slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                    <h3 class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-truncate" title="Order Form"
                        style="font-size: 18px;">Product Selection</h3> </div>
                <div class="slds-col slds-no-flex slds-align-bottom">
                    <p style="color: #8992A1;" id="header-info">
                        No item added
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <apex:form style="background: #F8F9FB;">
            <div style="padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;">
            <div id="entry-list">
                <div class="slds-form--stacked">
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-input__icon slds-icon-text-default">
                                <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0121_Order,'/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search')}"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <input type="text" class="slds-input search" id="search" placeholder="Enter product name or product code" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                        <apex:selectList styleClass="slds-select " id="pricebook" style="height:34px;"
                                         value="{!selectedPricebook}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!loadPricebookEntries}" rerender="entryList"
                                                oncomplete="makeOptionList()"/>
                            <!--<apex:selectOption itemLabel="Select a pricebook"
                                               itemValue=""></apex:selectOption>-->
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!PricebookOptions}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p class="slds-text-heading--label slds-truncate" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom:10px;"
                   title="Products">Products</p>
                <apex:outputPanel id="entryList">

                    <ul class="list slds-list--vertical slds-has-cards--space">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!pricebookEntries}" var="entry">
                            <li class="slds-list__item" style="background: white;">
                                <div class="slds-tile slds-tile--board slds-media">

                                    <div class="slds-media__figure">
                                        <div class="slds-icon slds-icon-standard-product">
                                            <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0121_Order,'/assets/icons/standard/product_60.png')}"
                                                         width="40"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                                        <div class="slds-grid">
                                            <div  class="slds-col slds-size--3-of-4">
                                                <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                                                    <p class="slds-tile__title slds-truncate"><a class="name"><apex:outputField value="{!entry.Product2.Name}"/></a></p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body--small">
                                                    <p class="slds-truncate code">
                                                        <apex:outputField value="{!entry.Product2.ProductCode}" />
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                        <apex:outputField value="{!entry.UnitPrice}" />
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div  class="slds-col slds-size--1-of-4">
                                                <button type="button" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" style="float:right;width:40px;padding:0;" 
                                                        onclick="addToOrder('{!JSINHTMLENCODE(entry.Id)}','{!JSINHTMLENCODE(entry.Product2.Name)}','{!entry.UnitPrice}');">
                                                    <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0121_Order,'/assets/icons/utility/add_60.png')}"
                                                         width="20"/>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </ul>
                </apex:outputPanel>

            </div>

                <p class="slds-text-heading--label slds-truncate" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom:10px;"
                   title="Products">Your Products</p>
                <p class="slds-text-body--small" id="order-placeholder">
                    No product added yet...
                </p>
            </div>
            <div  id="order-table" style="display:none;">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
                        <th scope="col">
                            <span class="slds-truncate">QTY</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <span class="slds-truncate">Product</span>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <span class="slds-truncate"></span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="order-list">
                    <!-- sample entry
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td data-label="QTY">
                            <span class="slds-truncate">
                                <input type="number" class="slds-input" style="width:50px;"/>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Product name">
                            <a class="slds-truncate">Product name</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="slds-row-action">
                            <div style="float:right;">
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--hint slds-button__icon--medium">
                                    <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0121_Order,'/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}"></use>
                                </svg>
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Remove</span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>-->
                </tbody>
            </table>

            </div>
            <div style="padding: 20px; min-height: 80px;">
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <button type="button" onclick="RefreshButton()" class="slds-button slds-button--brand " id="refresh" disabled="false">
                        Refresh
                    </button>                    
                    <button type="button" onclick="clearOrder()" class="slds-button slds-button--neutral ">
                        Clear
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="createOrder()" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" id="submit" disabled="disabled">
                        Add
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>

        </apex:form>
    </div>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.FastOrderJs, 'jquery.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.FastOrderJs, 'list.min.js')}"/>
    <script src="/support/console/35.0/integration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var DisableFlag = 'true';
        //sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/' + orderId, true);
        var orders = [];
    var options = {
        valueNames: [ 'name', 'code'],
        page: 5,
    };
    var entryList = new List('entry-list', options);
    function makeOptionList() {
        entryList = new List('entry-list', options);
        RefreshButtonDisplay(DisableFlag);

    }
    function updateHeaderInfo() {
        if (orders.length === 0) {
            $('#header-info').html('No item added'); 
        } else if (orders.length === 1) {
            $('#header-info').html('<a>1 item added</a>'); 
        } else {
            $('#header-info').html('<a>' + orders.length + ' items added</a>'); 
        }
    }
    function addToOrder(entryId, entryName, entryPrice) {
        $('#order-table').css('display','block');
        $('#order-placeholder').css('display','none');
        $('#submit').prop('disabled',false);
        var index = findOrderItem(entryId);
        if (index > -1) {
            ++orders[index].Quantity;
            $('#' + entryId).val(orders[index].Quantity);
        } else {
            orders.push({ Id: entryId, Price: entryPrice, Quantity: 1});
            $('#order-list').append('<tr class="slds-hint-parent"><td data-label="QTY">' +
                                   '<span class="slds-truncate">' + 
                                    '<input type="number" class="slds-input quantity" style="width:60px;border:none;"' + 
                                    ' value="1" min="1" onchange="changeQuantity(this, \'' +
                                    entryId + '\')" id="'+ entryId + '"/> ' +
                                   '</span></td><td data-label="Product Name"><a class="slds-truncate">' +
                                    entryName + '</a></td><td class="slds-row-action"><div style="float:right;cursor:pointer;" onclick="removeEntry(this, \'' 
                                    + entryId + '\')">' +
                                    '<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon--hint slds-button__icon--medium">' +
                                    '<use xlink:href="' + 
                                    "{!URLFOR($Resource.SLDS0121_Order,'/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close')}" + 
                                    '"></use>' +
                                    '</svg></div></td></tr>'
                                   );
        }
        updateHeaderInfo();
    }
    function changeQuantity(quantity, entryId) {
        var index = findOrderItem(entryId);
        orders[index].Quantity = $(quantity).val();
    }
    function removeEntry(quantity, entryId) {
        var index = findOrderItem(entryId);
        if (index > -1) {
            orders.splice(index, 1);
            $(quantity).parent().parent().remove();
        }
        if (orders.length === 0) {
            $('#order-placeholder').css('display','block');
            $('#order-table').css('display','none');
            $('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        updateHeaderInfo();
    }
    function findOrderItem(entryId) {
        for(var i = 0; i < orders.length; ++i) {
            if (orders[i].Id === entryId) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    function clearOrder() {
        orders = [];
        $('#order-list').html('');
        $('#order-placeholder').css('display','block');
        $('#order-table').css('display','none');
        $('#submit').prop('disabled',true);
        $('#search').val('');
        updateHeaderInfo();
    }
    function createOrder() {
        //var details = { 
        //    AccountId: '{!Opportunity.Account.Id}',
        //    Status: 'Draft',
        //    EffectiveDate: new Date(),
        //    Pricebook2Id: $('select[id*="pricebook"]').val(),
        //};
        //var order = new SObjectModel.Order();
        //order.create(details, function(err) {
        //    if(err) { 
        //        console.log(err);
        //        alert(err.message);
        //    }
        //    else {
        //        console.log('order created: ' + order.get('Id')); // Id is set when create completes
        //        createOrderItems(order.get('{!Opportunity.Id}'));
        //    }
        //});

        createOrderItems('{!Opportunity.Id}');
        clearOrder();
        //RefreshPrimaryTab();
        DisableFlag = "false";
        RefreshButtonDisplay(DisableFlag);
    }

    function createOrderItems(orderId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; ++i) {
            var details = {
                OpportunityId: orderId,
                UnitPrice: orders[i].Price,
                PricebookEntryId: orders[i].Id,
                Quantity: orders[i].Quantity,
            };
            var orderItem = new SObjectModel.OpportunityLineItem();
            orderItem.create(details, function(err) {
                if(err) { 
                    console.log(err);
                    alert(err.message);
                }
                else {
                    // this is the OLI
                    console.log(orderItem.log());     // Dump OLI to log
                    console.log(orderItem.get('Id')); // Id is set when create completes
                }
            });
        }
        openSubtab('/' + orderId);
    }

    function openSubtab(subtabUrl)
    {
        // Use the results primary tab id and open a new subtab
        //var openSubtab = function(result)
        //{
        //    sforce.console.openSubtab(result.id, subtabUrl, true);    
        //};
        //sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab);

    }

    function RefreshButtonDisplay(dFlag)
    {
        if(dFlag  == 'true') {
            $('#refresh').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
            $('#refresh').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    }

    function RefreshButton()
        {
            RefreshPrimaryTab();
            DisableFlag = "true";
            RefreshButtonDisplay(DisableFlag);
        }

    function RefreshPrimaryTab() 
        {
            sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(showTabId);
        }

        var showTabId = function showTabId(result) 
        {
            var tabId = result.id;
            //alert('Primary Tab IDs: primaryTabId ' + tabId );
            sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tabId , true, refreshSuccess);
        };

        var refreshSuccess = function refreshSuccess(result) 
        {
            //Report whether refreshing the primary tab was successful
            if (result.success == true) 
            {
                //alert('Primary tab refreshed successfully');
                RefreshButtonDisplay(DisableFlag);
            } 
            else 
            {
                //alert('Primary did not refresh');
            }
        };

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (pricebooks.size() > 0) {
        selectedPricebook = pricebooks[0].Id;
    }
```

Would be changed to:

```
    selectedPricebook = opp.Pricebook2Id;
```

Make sure you include {!Opportunity.Pricebook2Id} somewhere in your page so that the SOQL query built for your page will contain the data for your controller. Something like this:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="false">{!Opportunity.Pricebook2Id}</apex:outputText>
```